# invalid operation error from glTexImage3D call

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

```
        glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D,
                0,
                GL_R8I,
                4,
                4,
                4,
                0,
                GL_RED,
                GL_BYTE,
                (ByteBuffer)null);
```

This throws the invalid operation error (got from glGetError).

If I change the R8I to R8, no error is thrown.

Im trying to get integers fetched from the texture and the normalize format of R8 does not work for me.

WHy is R8I throwing an error when the specification seems to say that R8I is an acceptable format for this call.

I am using LWJGL for openGL.

Comment: What version of OpenGL do you use?

Comment: @Unick My system supports 4.0+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GL_R8I` is an integer format and should be used along with `GL_RED_INTEGER` instead of `GL_RED`.